# Parallel Extension & locking - C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am reading the excellent [article](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx) on Parallel extensions by Joe Albahari. He says,

> Leveraging multiple cores is easy for
>   most server applications, where each
>   thread can independently handle a
>   separate client request, but is harder
>   on the desktop — because it typically
>   requires that you take your
>   computationally intensive code and do
>   the following:
>
> 1. Partition it into small chunks.
> 2. Execute those chunks in parallel via multithreading.
> 3. Collate the results as they become available, in a thread-safe and
>      performant manner.
>
> Although you can do all of this with
>   the classic multithreading constructs,
>   it’s awkward — particularly the steps
>   of partitioning and collating. A
>   further problem is that the usual
>   strategy of locking for thread safety
>   causes a lot of contention when many
>   threads work on the same data at once.
>
> The PFX libraries have been designed
>   specifically to help in these
>   scenarios.

I am wondering how `PFX` reduces the contension?

AFAIK, threads are managed by the operating system and OS is responsible for providing and releasing locks. Everything else like `PFX` are abstractions on top of this which handles the locking well and tries to do the work with very minimal lock. I guess this is possible with even directly manipulating threads and locking carefully to avoid contension.

Is this correct? Or is there a better way to do thread safe operation with out using locks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of work went into PFX's partitioning, and also enhancing the `ThreadPool` to have work-stealing queues. Between these two, a lot of contention is eliminated (compared to a standard shared producer/consumer queue approach).